# Bernoulli inequality application

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction

On some level of math in school we learn about Bernoulli's inequality.

Proof of its correctness is very common in textbooks as exercise, when we learn mathematical induction.

Is Bernoulli's inequality interesting just because "it looks good" and "it's good exercise for learning induction" or has it some real-world application?

Comment: What do you mean by "real world application"? It is used to help solve other mathematical problems, but how would there be an application of the inequality in and of itself in the real world? The sum for the first $n$ positive integers...does that have an application, really? Etc.